# Do QSettings handle windows registry changes?

Tags: qt, registry

I´m using settings to read/write values inside windows registry. I would like to be able to reload those values if changes happened.

Actually, this kind of event can be handled with: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724892(v=vs.85).aspx (didn´t test it).

I don´t want to use windows specific code. Then, do QSettings handle registry changes?

Comment: Why do you need to track the registry changes in the first place? Reading settings will always give you the actual values.

Comment: I read it at the launch of the application. And it´s possible than an outside application change those values.

Comment: You can read settings just before you need the values. No need to cache them in the application.

Comment: If you are making a "watcher", you should use WinAPI. And based on this events - do necessary logic, probably through `QSettings`. Don't forget to call `QSettings::sync` immediately before reading new values, because in some cases they are cached insight an instance of `QSettings`.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov, ok, so there is no Qt stuff doing it by default.
Thanks for your replies.